# Python 3 Function is returning None. GCD and Euclid

Tags: python, python-3.x

This python 3 code is returning None for me when clearly it should be returning 12. I can't figure it out.

```
from math import *

def gcd(m,n):

    print("gcd: ",m,", ",n,")")

    if n == 0:
        print(m)
        return m
    else:
        gcd(n,m//n)

def main():

    m = 60
    n = 24
    result = gcd(m,n)
    print(result)

main()
```

Comment: I don't know if you're doing this as an exercise, but there's already a gcd function in `fractions`: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd

Answer (score 4):

Change the line

```
gcd(n,m//n)
```

to

```
return gcd(n,m//n)
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks! Can I get some kind of explanation? Why are you suppose to return it?

Comment: If you don't explicitly say return, the function will return None. Just calling and evaluating gcd(n,m//n) doesn't do anything. (do you perhaps have a background in R, or in a functional programming language?)

Comment: @Jpy: Same reason you write `return m` instead of just `m`, you write `return gcd(...)` instead of just `gcd(...)`